# How to use nested try/catch in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I have following code, in which i have to handle exception for 2 statements,

2nd line and 4th line

```
if(re.search("USN:.*MediaRenderer", datagram, flags=re.IGNORECASE)):
    deviceXML = re.search("LOCATION:(.*.xml)", datagram, flags=re.IGNORECASE).group(1)   # this line            
    root = ElementTree.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen(XMLLocation).read())                
    friendlyName = root.find('.//{}friendlyName'.format(Server.namespace)).text   # this line
    if not friendlyName in deviceList.keys():
       deviceList[friendlyName] = host
    self.model.setStringList(deviceList.keys())
```

How can i use nested try/catch here

I tried following way:

```
if(re.search("USN:.*MediaRenderer", datagram, flags=re.IGNORECASE)):
        try:
            deviceXML = re.search("LOCATION:(.*.xml)", datagram, flags=re.IGNORECASE).group(1)            
            root = ElementTree.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen(XMLLocation).read())                
            try:
                friendlyName = root.find('.//{}friendlyName'.format(Server.namespace)).text
                print "\n fname = ", friendlyName
                if not friendlyName in deviceList.keys():
                    deviceList[friendlyName] = host
                self.model.setStringList(deviceList.keys())                
        except:
            pass
```

This is giving me indentation error for except line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inner `try` block is missing an `except` clause (which is required).

```
try:
    # do something risky

    try:
        # do another risky thing
    except:  # <-- this is required
        # handle the inner exception

except Exception as exc:
    # handle outer exception
```

---

But you may want to restructure your code to have two separate blocks.  It will be cleaner that way and easier to understand/maintain.

```
if(re.search("USN:.*MediaRenderer", datagram, flags=re.IGNORECASE)):
    try:
        deviceXML = re.search("LOCATION:(.*.xml)", datagram, flags=re.IGNORECASE).group(1)            
        root = ElementTree.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen(XMLLocation).read())                

    except:
        # return, break, etc.

    # no exception from previous block; proceed with processing

    try:
        friendlyName = root.find('.//{}friendlyName'.format(Server.namespace)).text
        print "\n fname = ", friendlyName
        if not friendlyName in deviceList.keys():
            deviceList[friendlyName] = host
        self.model.setStringList(deviceList.keys())                

    except Exception as exc:
        # do something with the error here
```

Comment: having 2 except is not giving me any o/p

Comment: Okay.  Can't help you with no output unless you post your code.  (But this answer illustrates how to use nested exceptions.)